# C# get distinct and max value

Tags: c#, linq, max, distinct

This is my datatable

```
X       Y   P
Str1    C1  10
Str1    C1  5
Str1    C1  1
Str1    C1  2
Str2    C1  25
Str2    C1  4
Str1    C2  411
Str1    C2  2356
Str2    C2  12
Str2    C2  33
```

I am trying to get distinct rows based on X and Y columns and get max value of P column using linq to dataset

```
 X      Y   P
Str1    C1  10
Str2    C1  25
Str1    C2  2356
Str2    C2  33
```

-

```
            var query0 = (from row in tablo.AsEnumerable() 

        select new
        {
            X = row.Field<string>("X"),
            Y = row.Field<string>("Y"),

        }).Distinct();
```

How can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `GroupBy` here:-

```
var result = tablo.AsEnumerable().
                  .GroupBy(row => new 
                            { 
                               X= row.Field<string>("X"), 
                               Y = row.Field<string>("Y") 
                            })
                  .Select(x => new 
                              {
                                 X = x.Key.X,
                                 Y = x.Key.Y,
                                 P = x.Max(z => z.Field<int>("P"))
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
 var result =  tablo.AsEnumerable() 
                    .Select(row=> new
                    {
                       X = row.Field<string>("X"),
                       Y = row.Field<string>("Y"),
                       P = row.Filed<int>("P")
                    }).GroupBy(i=>new {X = i.X, Y = i.Y})
                      .Select(gr=>new{
                          X = gr.Key.X,
                          Y = gr.Key.Y
                          P = gr.Max(z => z.P)
                    });
```

Essentially, we first declare a sequence of an anoymous type objects, that have three properties, `X`, `Y` and `P`. Then we group by this sequence based on `X` and `Y`. Last, we pick up the maximum price for each group.